# Variable Access Between Function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, self

In my GUI design, I want to seperate `menuBar()`, `statusBar()`, `addToolBar()` etc.
The problem I'm facing is not to know how to reach `open_file` variable of `menuBar()` function for `addToolBar()`.

I know that If I define `open_file` as `self.open_file`, I can reach it where ever I want. However, I'm tring to figure out alternative way without using self. for each variable for further coding.

When I search that, I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822894/13185146)
But, I think that calling variables with this method may cause confusion or noise in the GUI design.

Here is my code,

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        title = "General Body"
        top = 100
        left = 350
        width = 600
        height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left, top, width, height)

        self.menu_bar()
        self.status_bar()
        self.tool_bars()

    def menu_bar(self):
        bar_menu = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = bar_menu.addMenu("File")
        # viewMenu = bar.addMenu("View")
        # editMenu = bar.addMenu("Edit")
        # searchMenu = bar.addMenu("Search")
        # toolMenu = bar.addMenu("Tool")
        # helpMenu = bar.addMenu("Help")

        # File Menu =========================
        open_file = QAction("Open", self)
        open_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        open_file.setStatusTip("Open File")

        save_file = QAction("Save", self)
        save_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        save_file.setStatusTip("Save File")

        exit_file = QAction("Exit", self)
        exit_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exit_file.setStatusTip("Close Program")
        exit_file.triggered.connect(self.exit_file_func)

        file_menu.addAction(open_file)
        file_menu.addAction(save_file)
        file_menu.addAction(exit_file)

    def status_bar(self):
        bar_status = self.statusBar()
        bar_status.showMessage("Read!")

    def tool_bars(self):
        tool_bar1 = self.addToolBar("Operations")
        tool_bar1.addAction(open_file)

    @staticmethod
    def exit_file_func():
        msg_exit = QMessageBox()
        msg_exit.setWindowTitle("Warning!")
        msg_exit.setText("Would you like to exit ?")
        msg_exit.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        msg_exit.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        msg_exit.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)
        x = msg_exit.exec()
        if x == msg_exit.Yes:
            QApplication.quit()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, I overcome the problem.

Here is part of my code;

```
def menu_bar(self):
    bar_menu = self.menuBar()
    file_menu = bar_menu.addMenu("File")

    # File Menu =========================

    open_file = QAction("Open", self)
    open_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
    open_file.setStatusTip("Open File")

    save_file = QAction("Save", self)
    save_file.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
    save_file.setStatusTip("Save File")

    return open_file, save_file
def tool_bars(self):
    a, b = self.menu_bar()
    tool_bar1 = self.addToolBar("Operations")
    tool_bar1.addAction(a)
    tool_bar1.addAction(b)
```

In this way, there looks no problem.
However, your feedback about the way i did, is still on table